# Proper way to generate a view from a many to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, razor, ado.net-entity-data-model, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have two tables - `ContactInformation` & `EmailAddress` - which have a many to many (* : *) relationship. After making this association in the ADO.NET data model and generate the db from it, a table titled `ContactInformationEmailAddresses` which maps the two tables is created in the Entities Container.

Unlike when I scaffold views which have a 1:* relationship, there's no entries available for its counterpart in the view when I scaffold either one and scaffolding off the combined table isn't an option even after updating the model from the db.

My question is simply: is there an automated way to generate the creation form for `ContactInformationEmailAddresses` that will have the EmailAddress entry field?

Comment: This sounds wrong. The new `ContactInformationEmailAddresses` has two 1:* relationships so should work. The scaffolding may be failing due to the lack of other fields to expose in a form. As a test you could add a temp extra field to the join table and update the entities. See if it will scaffold then?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, they actually have many to many because the requirements. A Person has 1 ContactInformation and vice versa but ContactInformations can have many EmailAddresses and they want People to be able to share EmailAddresses so many ContactInformations can have many EmailAddresses and vice versa. I could be implementing that requirement wrong though. I think I've found that it's not likely to be done automagically, and if it is I've already put more time into figuring out how than it takes to write the page so I've admitted defeat and carried on to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At present the scaffolding templates don’t support generating views that require the selection and association with more than one entity – the “many” end of the association.

Make sure to check out this blog article
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2013/09/20/managing-entity-relationships-with-mvc-scaffolding.aspx